# Jhipster - relationship (join) with another field (not id)

Tags: jhipster

I'm relatively new to JHipster.

> This application was generated using JHipster 3.12.1

I have the following jdl file:

```
entity Country {
    countryCd  String minlength(2) maxlength(2) required,
    countryNm  String maxlength(64) required
}

entity State{
     stateCd  String minlength(2) maxlength(2) required,
     stateNm  String maxlength(40) ,
     stateTypeCd  String maxlength(1) required
}

entity ZipCode{
     zipCd  String maxlength(20) required
}

entity ZipCodeGeoBrg{
     countryCd  String minlength(2) maxlength(2) required,
     zipCd  String maxlength(20) required,
     cityNm  String maxlength(100) required,
     stateCd  String minlength(2) maxlength(2) required,
     countyNm  String maxlength(100) ,
     countyCd  String maxlength(20) ,
     communityNm  String maxlength(100) ,
     communityCd  String maxlength(20) ,
     latitudeNum  BigDecimal ,
     longitudeNum  BigDecimal,
     accuracyNum  Integer 
}

relationship OneToMany {
    ZipCode{zipCodeGeoBrg} to ZipCodeGeoBrg{zipCode(zipCd)},
    Country{zipCodeGeoBrg(countryCd)} to ZipCodeGeoBrg{country(countryCd)},
    State{zipCodeGeoBrg(stateCd)} to ZipCodeGeoBrg{state(stateCd)}
}

dto * with mapstruct

service all with serviceImpl
search ZipCodeGeoBrg with elasticsearch
```

The jdl documentation states:

> By default, the joining is done by the id field… But if you want the joining to be done by another field, then you can do things like:
>
> entity A {
>          name String required
>      }
>      entity B
>
> relationship OneToOne {
>          A{b} to B{a(name)}
>      }

The generated class (ZipCodeGeoBrg) has these attributes:

```
@ManyToOne
private ZipCode zipCode;

@ManyToOne
private Country country;

@ManyToOne
private State state;
```

My entity class is generated but all the joins are on the id columns, not the named columns (e.g. countryCd). I expected something like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn( name = "COUNTRY_CD" )
private Country country;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn( name = "STATE_CD" )
private State state;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn( name = "ZIP_CD" )
private ZipCode zipCode;
```

I've tried the jdl like this too:

```
relationship OneToMany {
    ZipCode to ZipCodeGeoBrg{zipCode(zipCd)},
    Country to ZipCodeGeoBrg{country(countryCd)},
    State to ZipCodeGeoBrg{state(stateCd)}
}
```

and got the same results.

This is an existing database. The DBA is willing to update the tables and add an ID column, but is not willing to redo all the relationships (e.g. zip_cd is the existing column that relates ZipCode <--> ZipCodeGeoBrg, and that's not going to change). So I have to make these work with columns that are not the ID. I know I can just update the Entities by hand after I generate, but I have 20 more tables to do and would rather have the tool do it for me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation has been updated since, it now reads:

> The join is always done using the id field which is also the default field shown when editing a relation in the front-end. If another field should be shown instead, you can specify it like this:

```
entity A {
   name String required
 }

 entity B
 relationship OneToOne {
  A{b} to B{a(name)}
 }
```

Which I understand as if the notation is not really for changing the join field, but to change the display field in the generated UI.

So what you wanted to do is probably not possible to get JHipster to do it, but you can always modify the generated code to fit your purpose.